# Get current date in Javascript even if the user changed their system clock?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, time, epoch

I want to retrieve the current UNIX epoch in Javascript. I can do this by doing:

```
const d = Date.now();
```

However, if the user changed their system clock or if their system clock was slightly off, this value would be inaccurate.

Is there any way to accurately retrieve the current UNIX epoch? My only thought was to query some sort of website, but that would introduce latency.

Is there an API in the browser perhaps that allows independent querying of the date without relying on the user's system?

Comment: Browsers are 100% dependent on the local platform for services like time-of-day. Querying a reliable server is your only option.

Comment: Maybe http://www.ntpjs.org/ does help.